# PHP Notice: Object of class Closure could not be converted to int

Tags: php

I'm getting a strange warning notice in my application. I'm using a custom `usort` function inside a class. This is how it looks:

```
class Class_Name
{
    function zstream_builder()
    {
            $array = some_array();
        //sort posts by date DESC
        usort($array, array('Class_Name', 'zstream_sorter')); // <- the notice is thrown on this line

        return $array;
    }

    private static function zstream_sorter($key = 'sort_str_date')
    {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key)
        {
            return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
        };
    }
}
```

this is the notice I get:

`Notice: Object of class Closure could not be converted to int in PATH_TO_FILE on line xx`

any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean to `usort( $array, self::zstream_sorter("the_key"))`?

Comment: @Esailija Yes you are correct. It's 6:45am on Saturday in my locale, in my defense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`usort` is going to call `Class_Name::stream_sorter` as *the comparison function*, passing it two arguments. The return value is a function, but `usort` expects an integer telling it which of the arguments was greater. You need to pass the return value of `Class_Name::stream_sorter` to `usort`, not the function itself:

```
usort($array, self::zstream_sorter());
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Although I modified the sorting function a bit, because the sorted array was an array of arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your compare function needs to return an int, not a function.

If you want to select your sort field, you should use

```
protected $key = 'sort_str_date';

function zstream_builder()
{
  $array = some_array();
  //sort posts by date DESC
  usort($array, array($this, 'z_sorter')); 

  return $array;
}

function z_sorter($a, $b) 
{
   return strnatcmp($a[$this->key], $b[$this->key]);
}
```